# How to install Xfce without xubuntu-desktop or ubuntustudio-desktop

Tags: 12.04, unity, xfce, xubuntu

I want to install Xfce **without xubuntu-desktop or ubuntustudio-desktop** (**original Xfce 4.10, without extras**). I too want to keep Unity (and Unity 2D) on my computer. Is the `xfce-meta` package great for that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 20.04, you can install Xfce 4 from the default repository:

```
sudo apt install xfce4
```

Thanks to @Frank Kusters, in the comments below, for this update.

---

**Previous answer:**

To install [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) 4.10 (the newest version of this desktop environment) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS you should follow these steps:

Add the ppa that will allow you to install the Xfce 4.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
```

Update the system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Xfce 4.10:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Comment: It is working now!

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, you can install `xfce4` without adding the PPA.